# Calling open in Terminal in MacOS brings another program to the foreground

Tags: macos, terminal

I have two application bundles (called ProgramA and ProgramB) that I have written for MacOS. If I use open in Terminal to launch one of them it will launch just fine. But if I try to use open to launch the other one while the first one is open, it will instead bring to the foreground the already launched app. For instance, if ProgramA is already open and I use `open -a ProgramB`, Program A will instead come to the foreground.

I know I can use `open -n -a ProgramB` to ensure a new app is launched, but I would like to keep the behavior of bringing the app to the foreground if it already running. If I double-click the icon in Finder the apps will open as expected. The apps are being launched by another app so just using Finder isn't an option.

I thought maybe the issue was a duplicate key in the Info.plist that is used by the system, but that doesn't seem to be an issue. The values for the following keys are unique between the two apps:

- CFBundleIdentifier
- CFBundleExecutable
- CFBundleName

Is there a way I can get open to launch the correct app if other app is already running?